# Couple of questions about connecting to a remote database in silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, database-connection, silverlight-5.0

I've found these tutorials:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/173124-silverlight-connecting-to-remote-database-wcf/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSDKPjRsDI4

But i'm not sure if they will work with silverlight 5 application.. does anyone know if the steps shown in the tutorials are the same for silverlight 5?

Also, these two tutorials seem to accomplish the same thing overall (connect to database and get information from database), but do it differently. Which way is the best way to connect to a database, execute sql queries, and display the results in silverlight 5?

thanks!

Comment: How about trying the steps in Silverlight 5 and if you get errors report on those errors or try to fix them..

Comment: Ok, i won't be able to try them until tomorrow and i was trying to get a headstart. I'll post back tomorrow to see if it works

Comment: That's about all I could suggest.. happy coding..

Comment: If that's the case Wiktor Zychla how can i run a query that's saved in a sql file? It's a gigantic query that eventually my program must run. I don't think i can just store in a string variable..

Comment: Store it as a Resource in the xap. Call Application.GetResourceStream()

Comment: Ok, so i've went through the first tutorial i have listed, Everything is good except i don't know what to set the string myConnectionString to. I think its supposed to specify the path to the database i want to connect to, but what is the format of this string?

Comment: Nevermind, i got the tutorial to work. Thanks for your help guys!